# Show VAT on invoices in Stripe using Checkout

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I configured Checkout in Stripe (the client version) for my Website. The price I propose includes VAT because I know there are problems with Taxes in Stripe.
But my clients are professionnals and I need to display the VAT on the invoice.
I created a tax in my dashboard (incluses calculus) and I coded in my server:

```
    const stripe = require('stripe')(stripeSecretKey);

stripe.invoices.update(
    'in_18jwqyLlRB0eXbMtrUQ97YBz',
    {
        default_tax_rates: [
            'txr_1F4NqUGMDnVbIGuN45auNGxZ',
        ],
    },
    function (err, invoice) {
        // asynchronously called
    }
)
module.exports = router;
```

When I test a payment, everything is working well but the VAT is not on my invoice. I'd like to apply this tax to all the invoices.